# CSS Media Query will change some styles but not others

Tags: html, css, frontend, media-queries

I'm trying to use a media query to change the color of an element, but after a lot of troubleshooting, I've found that the media query only changes some properties such as font-size and flex. It WON'T change color for some reason.

Here's the query:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .headerContainer{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .slash {
        color: red;
        font-size: 20rem;
    }
}
```

This is at the bottom of my stylesheet and nothing is overriding it. The '.slash' class contains some text in my HTML document.

I've tried moving the media query to the bottom of the stylesheet, changing other properties to make sure it works, using classes in HTML to target these elements directly... I've included the viewport meta tag in my HTML document as well. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: "nothing is overriding it". It's most likely that's not true. Have you inspected the element in the browser? The styles that are overridden are usually greyed out. You most likely need a more specific rule to target the color. Order in the CSS file won't help with that.

Comment: You should add the html in the question